# How to hide VictoryChart being used with VictoryPie as child?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

Im using VictoryPie as child for VictoryChart. I had to use it to resolve the use of the onLongPress event. But when i did it, the VictoryChart layout appeared behind my VictoryPìe component.

My Component:

```
<VictoryChart
 containerComponent={<VictoryContainer disableContainerEvents />}>
 <VictoryPie
  padAngle={({datum}) => datum.y + 2}
  width={335}
  innerRadius={10}
  labelRadius={({innerRadius}) => innerRadius + 45}
  colorScale={['#4D90FF']}
  style={{labels: {fill: 'white', fontSize: 14}}}
  data={btnState}
  labelComponent={<PlayAudio />}
  events={eventsArray}
 />
</VictoryChart>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGYp4.jpg)

I've tried many properties in victoryChart but none of them worked.

like:
style={{ parent: { border: "none"} }}
theme={{ axis: { style: { display: "none" } } }}

I want to remove the borders and numbers behind my VictoryPie.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using VictoryAxis.

```
<VictoryAxis
 style={{
  axis: {stroke: 'transparent'},
  ticks: {stroke: 'transparent'},
  tickLabels: {fill: 'transparent'},
 }}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).